# Is a hash table really O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

**The way I understand it, an hash table is an array of linked lists, so it should actually be O(n/array_length).

Isn't saying the it's O(1) just plain wrong?**

For example, if I have 1M items on hash table that is based on a 100-sized array, the average lookup would take 5,000 items. Clearly not O(1), although I assume that most implementations of a hash table use a much bigger sized array.

**And what is usually the array size that is being used in most languages' (JS, Go, etc) hash table implementations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  In general, it is not possible to say that *all* hash tables are `O(1)`.  It depends on some design decisions, and on other factors.

In your example, you seem to be talking about a hash table with a fixed number of buckets (100) and an unbounded number of entries `N`.  With that design, it will take on average `N / 50` comparisons to find a key that is present, and on average `N / 100` comparison to discover that a key is not present.  That is `O(N)`.

There is a common implementation strategy to deal with this.  As the hash table gets larger, you periodically resize the primary array, and then redistribute the keys / entries.  For example, the standard Java `HashMap` and `HashTable` classes track the ratio of the array size and the number of entries.  When the ratio exceeds a configurable *load factor*, the primary array size ts doubled.  (See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for an explanation of the load factor.)

The analysis of this is complicated.  However, if we can assume that keys are roughly evenly distributed across the buckets, we get the following:

- average lookup times that are `O(1)`
- average insertion times that are `O(1)`
- worst-case insertion times that are `O(N)` ... when the insertion triggers a resize.

What if the key distribution is badly skewed?

This can happen if the hash function is a poor one, or if the process that generates the keys is pathological.

Well, if you don't do anything about it, the worst case occurs when all keys have the same hash value and end up in the same bucket ... irrespective of the primary array size.  This results in `O(N)` lookup and insertion.

But there are a couple of ways to mitigate this.  A simple way is to perform a second hashing operation on the key's hashcodes. This helps in some cases.  A more complex way is to replace the hash chains with balanced binary trees.  This changes the average behavior of lookup and insertion (for the case of pathological keys) from `O(N)` to O(logN)`.

From Java 8 onwards, the `HashMap` implementation uses either hash chains or trees, depending on the number of keys in a given bucket.

---

> And what is usually the array size that is being used in most languages' (JS, Go, etc) hash table implementations?

For Java (and probably for the others) the array size changes over the life-time of the hash table as described above.  In Java, there is an upper limit on the size or the array.  Java arrays can only have 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 elements.

Comment: So ideally a hash table array size should be at least N (=size of items in table)?

Comment: In practice, less that `N` is fine.  (In Java the default load factor is `0.75`.)  But the size needs to be *proportional to `N`*.

Comment: 0.75 in the equation m/n ?

Comment: What equation "m/n"?   I provided a link in my answer for you to read about the load factor ...

Answer (score 1):

In the implementations you mention, the array starts small, and is reallocated with a bigger size as more elements are added.

The array size stays within a constant factor of the element count, so that the average number of elements per slot is bounded.